# Avoid having to two touch events triggered at the same time

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView with rows. On each of these rows, on the right edge, there is a button A (with a small width) that triggers a segue.

On each row, the `commitEditingStyle Delete` is activated.

My problem is that when I swipe on the left (to trigger the deletion), if I do it from the edge, as the button A is pretty small, I get the "delete" button on the row appearing (which is what I want), but I also trigger the segue as the swipe is too fast and the button thinks I tapped on it.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Just a suggestion, try adding your button A directly on cell instead of 'cell.contentView' !!

Comment: Well it seems on the Interface Builder it's not possible

Comment: remove the segue action from that little button and use the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndex for the segue , so when u swipe the row then no segue will be perform

Comment: I actually have another segue for the didSelectRowAtIndex